# Layer attribute data being deleted

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I've been using QGIS to make maps showing concentrations of study sites across regions of a country. Making the maps is ok, not problem. However, I have found, three times today, that when I close the file and then come back later (after saving and saving a copy to be sure) that the attribute data in both copies is no longer there, leaving only empty layers.
I'm at a loss as to why this is, but I have noticed that it is only in the data frames that I have conducted Joine attributes so that I can link point data with shapefiles, although both the original shapefile and point data files are intact within the QGIS environment.
I'm using QGS 3.36 'Maidenhead'

Answer (score 4):

When you use any tool in qgis the default output is a memory layer, these memory are not saved with the project and are lost when the project is closed.

To prevent this you could :

- Set an actual file name and location in the output setting of tool
- Manually save the tool result after checking it is right for your use (right click and "save as..." or clicking on
  the memory icon on the right of the layer name)
- Use the memory layer saver plugin (the layer are saved along the
  project file but still appear as a memory layer in qgis)

Comment: Joining via layer properties is another option (for a non-spatial join), rather than using the processing tool.